# NetSuite Integration With SSIS

Tags: ssis, netsuite

I am working on NetSuite ,I have SQL database which i want to synchronize with NetSuite. I am trying to use SSIS package for that is it possible to do and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for most NetSuite data it is possible. One way to do it is through NetSuite's SOAP api's(this is fairly involved, so their are links below), though there may be other ways as well.

Additionally, there are several third party software company's that provide appliances to  do this as well and a few that give instructions on how to setup integration.

For example:
http://www.cdata.com/drivers/netsuite/ssis/ 
http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/netsuite-api are two examples that provide software to use SSIS to sync a SQL database with Netsuite

This link talks about how you can do it without third parties: https://sysaux.wordpress.com/2015/06/27/escaping-netsuites-cloud-migrating-legacy-netsuite-erp-data-to-sql-server-via-ssis-reporting-with-ssrs-and-sharepoint-2013/
as does this one: http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.com/2013/11/using-ssis-to-consume-data-from.html